# What is this view or frame called?

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm now learning to write a simple iPhone program. Does anyone know how does the following effect created, i.e., the checkmark?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in view or control which provides this, but a common third-party one (which also supports progress indicators) is [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD).

Answer (score 1):

That seems to me a HUD. There are a lot of alternatives to make a similar effect:

- https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD
- https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: you are wellcome, i use SVProgressHUD in my projects too

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in effect for this.  You can achieve this with a UIImageView with a checkbox image.  Set the UIImageView alpha to .3f.